# Automatically make maps from point file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, data-driven-pages

Please forgive me if this is an overly basic or broad question. I am a competent user of ArcGIS.

I have a shapefile containing thousands of points. I'd like to automatically make a map of **each** point, in which:

1. The name of the finished map is the name of an attribute of the point
2. The point is symbolized a certain way
3. A polygon is chosen from another shapefile based upon the location of the point
4. That polygon is symbolized a certain way
5. Text populates a box on the map containing attributes from both the point and the polygon
6. The polygon is labelled with an expression and in a certain format
7. among a few other requirements.

I can batch export mxds to pdfs. I can batch rename documents. I'm familiar with data driven pages. I can make one of the maps in a few minutes, but I have hundreds to make.  Help point me in the right direction - is this a job for Python, Model Builder, or something else? I'm willing to spend some time learning, but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: I think this is too broad for the focussed Q&A we do here but all those requirements sound like Data Driven Pages with a bit of ArcPy to me so between using the help and researching them one at a time here you should be able to achieve what you are trying to.

Comment: Yes I agree with PolyGeo.

Comment: I thought it might not be a suitable question for this forum. Thanks for considering it and for the advice.